(Fake-)proving the diagonal of a separated variety is a closed immersion
In class we were given this exercise:

Show that if $X$ is a separated variety, then the diagonal $\Delta: X \to X \times X$ is a closed immersion.

The naive argument that came to mind is that, regardless of whether $\Delta(X)$ is closed, $\Delta$ always induces an isomorphism of varieties $X \to \Delta(X)$, given by $x \mapsto (x, x)$ with inverse $(x, x) \mapsto x$, so then the fact that $X$ is separated gives us by definition that $\Delta(X)$ is closed and hence $\Delta$ a closed immersion.
However, I now see that the image $\Delta(X)$ is not necessarily a variety, so the concept of morphism of varieties into $\Delta(X)$ doesn't even exist. Is this what is wrong with this proof?
In general, the Image of a morphism of varieties doesn't exist (in the category of varieties). But maybe for this special morphism, the diagonal morphism, it does exist?
For example, it seems that, at least topologically, the diagonal of the line with two origins (which is not separated) is just another copy of itself?

Definitions
$\def\O{\mathcal{O}} \def\Var\{\mathrm{\bf Var}} \def\Aff{\mathrm{\bf Aff}} \def\A{\mathbb{A}} \def\F\{\mathcal{F}} \def\G{\mathcal{G}} \def\Top{\mathrm{\bf Top}}$Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let us define a variety as a locally ringed space that admits a finite open cover such that each open thereof is isomorphic (as a locally ringed space) to an affine algebraic set with its sheaf of regular functions.
A morphism between varieties $(X, \F)$ and $(Y, \G)$ is defined as a morphism of locally ringed spaces, which is a pair $(f, f^\#)$ where $f: X \to Y$ is a topological morphism and $f^\#: \G \to f_*\F$ is a morphism of sheaves of local rings (sending maximal to maximal in stalks).
So we get a category $\Var$ which is a full subcategory of the category of locally ringed spaces.
A variety is said to be separated if the image of the diagonal $\Delta : X \to X \times X$ is a closed subvariety of $X \times X$, the latter being the product variety.
A closed immersion of varieties is a morphism of varieties whose image is a closed subvariety of the codomain and that restricts to an isomorphism of varieties onto its image.


This is a complete tangent and not helpful for the answer, but do you know the analogous result in topology? I remember it is something like 'A T1 space $X$ is T2 if and only the diagonal is closed in $X \times X$', but maybe I am forgetting some condition here. Is T2 (aka Hausdorff) the property that 'separated' in algebraic geometry tries to mimic?

@Vincent Yes that's the analogous for topological spaces, and motivates the definition of separated for varieties.

I might be missing something. But doesn't the very definition of separated already imply that $\Delta(X)$ is a closed subvariety, hence in particular a variety? So your question is why it is a closed immersion (i.e. restricts to an isomorphism)?

@ClemensB Yes, exactly. In my argument, I was saying that for any $X$ (not necessarily separated), $X \cong \Delta(X)$, but in this setting $\Delta(X)$ might not be a subvariety.
